# Deploying With Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been attempting to deploy using elastic beanstalk, but I've had no luck. Every time I get the error

```
Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command     01_syncdb failed
```

Here's my workstudy.config file inside .ebextenstions directory

```
container_commands:
   01_syncdb:    
     command: "manage.py syncdb --noinput"
     leader_only: true

 option_settings:
   - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
     option_name: WSGIPath
     value: workstudy/wsgi.py
   - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
     value: workstudy.settings
   - option_name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
     value: ************
   - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
     value: ***********
```

Here's my database settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
```

Here's my requirements.txt file

```
Django==1.6.5
MySQL-python==1.2.5
South==1.0
boto==2.30.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.2.1
sqlparse==0.1.11
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I also tried changing the command to django-admin.py but that didn't work either. Any help would be great thanks

Comment: First thing I would recommend is trying to look at the detailed error logs. This is how you can get logs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

Comment: Are you sure that your yaml format is valid?

Answer (score 0):

You should source virtualenv scope, before running any app related code and manage.py is part of your application:

```
  01_syncdb:    
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```